# Automatic assignment of tickets with Trac

Tags: automation, trac, ticket-system

I'm using **Trac** (v0.11), and I'd like to:

1. automatically assign a ticket to someone, as it's opened, basing on certain rules
2. hide the "assign to" and "CC" fields from the "new ticket" screen

How can I do that (scripting, workflows, etc.)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point 1 is solved using **Components**, standard Trac entities that can be associated to an automatic assignee of the Ticket.

Point 2 is solved by the powerful [BlackMagicTicketTweaks](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/BlackMagicTicketTweaksPlugin) plugin (it hides, disables or changes the name of fields on the Ticket form).

Comment: Could you expand on the use of *Components* in order to automatically assign a ticket to someone? I can see how to set the default component but not how this is associated with a default assignee...

Comment: I use the Admin->Components screen of TRAC and I've associated each component to an "user". As the ticket is opened on that Component, it is automatically assigned to the correct user.

Comment: I think you're talking about a ticket's default owner, not it's assignee. My tickets are also, by default, assigned to an owner, but if I understood the question from the OP correctly (and my own question), is it possible to automatically have a ticket change from status "new" (with or without default owner) to assigned to a user. Or did I miss something still?

Comment: No, it doesn't change automatically. Its just a default value on ticket creation.